# How do I make git blame’s default coloring consistent with my terminal’s colorscheme?

Tags: git-config, git-blame

The default `git blame` colors don’t match the light colorscheme that might terminal uses:

[image: A screenshot of a terminal with an output from git blame on the left.]

On the left you can see a dark output of `git blame`, and on the right you can see my Tokyonight day colorscheme. It looks like `git blame` just doesn’t reuse my terminal’s colorscheme.

Is it possible to configure Git to use the default coloring strategy but with terminal-consistent colors?

Changing the `blame.coloring` config from `none` to `highlightRecent` fixes the immediate problem: Git reuses the terminal’s colors, but it’s a different coloring strategy. I’d like to keep the different background shade per commit behavior.